# Cast BigDecimal Const to int

Tags: java, bigdecimal

i have this `const`:

```
public static final BigDecimal IND = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
```

i want to use it on a `switch` statement like this:

```
int value =  key.getCision().intValue();
switch (value) {
    case PreEtat.IND:
    //******
    break;
    //****
    default:
    break;
}
```

i have this error for this line : `case PreEtat.IND:`

***Error:***

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from BigDecimal to int
```

Comment: Switch case statements with decimals values seems to be a bad idea. Don't you prefer using enums?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle have you an example please

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [`BigDecimal.intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue--):

> Converts this BigDecimal to an int. This conversion is analogous to a
>   narrowing primitive conversion from double to short as defined in the
>   Java Language Specification: any fractional part of this BigDecimal
>   will be discarded, and if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit
>   in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. Note that this
>   conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude and
>   precision of this BigDecimal value as well as return a result with the
>   opposite sign.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers and Strings).

The `case PreEtat.IND` in your `switch` refers to a `BigDecimal` constant, which will not compile.

You probably want to initialize and test an `int` constant by invoking `intValue` on the `BigDecimal` instance.

Worth noting, you are losing the decimal part of your number, which makes the conditional test in your `switch` a little weird.